# Adding zero sharp via forcing

Tags: logic, set-theory

Well of course $0^\sharp$ cannot be added by forcing. What I mean is the following. Suppose $0^\sharp$ exists. Let $\mathbb{P}=\mathrm{Add}(\omega,1)$ be the Cohen poset, and $L^\mathbb{P}$ be the class of $\mathbb{P}$-names in $L$. Let $W=\{\sigma[0^\sharp]:\sigma\in L^\mathbb{P}\}$ where $\sigma[0^\sharp]$ is the interpretation of the name $\sigma$ using (the filter corresponding to) $0^\sharp$. Is it true that $W=L[0^\sharp]$? Clearly $W\subseteq L[0^\sharp]$. For the reverse direction, it's enough to show $W\models\mathsf{ZF}$, for which it's enough to show $W$ is closed under Gödel operations, since it's the union of a cumulative hierarchy. It seems plausible that this is just an exercise in writing down names, but I'm a little uncertain due to the filter being non-generic: Exercise IV.2.47 in Kunen shows that for non-generic filters, the "extension" may not be closed under set complement (but maybe that doesn't happen for filters corresponding to reals?).

Comment: Since $\omega_1^L<\omega_1^{L[0^\#] }$, it won't be Cohen generic. But that's a really nice question.